# Can an array in JavaScript have two values associated with one option?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I want to achieve something like the code below in JavaScript, how can I do it?

```
const ArrayName = [
  { result: "1. text1", value1: 30, value2: 8 },
  { result: "2. text2", value1: 1.95, value2: 9 },
  { result: "3. text3.", value1: 10.9, value2: 10 },
];
```

When I execute the code, I get:

```
ERROR
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:730:61
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:723:33)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:22413:22)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:25699:17)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:26995:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:12005:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:12049:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:12106:35)
    at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:31980:11)
```

Comment: `If I want to achieve something similar to the code below in react, how can I do it?` Similar... how? And what role does react play in it?

Comment: Just like the code, but it doesn't work, but I want this kind of function.

Comment: The code looks fine

Comment: `Just like the code, but it doesn't work` What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: If a user chooses one option, then there are two values associated with that choice.

Comment: Well, that's perfectly valid javascript. you do it *exactly*  like inthe shown code .... Unless of course, you didn't explain well enough what you really need

Answer (score 2):

With all chance you'd want:

```js
const ArrayName = [
  { result: "1. text1", values:[30, 8] },
  { result: "2. text2", values: [1.95, 9] },
  { result: "3. text3.", values: [10.9, 10] },
];
```

And reference them in a loop like:

```js
ArrayName.map(({ result, values }) => {
  // do something with values[0]
  // do something with values[1]
});
```